# Who sends the "Letter from Friend"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Who sends the letters in Skyrim through courier as *Letter from Friend*, locating new shouts?

> You caused a bit of stir in `<Location>` when you demonstrated the power
>   of your Thu'um. Not everyone is anxious for the return of the
>   Dragonborn.
>
> I for one desire to see you grow and develop your talents. Skyrim
>   needs a true hero these days.
>
> You should turn your attention to `<Location>`. I understand it holds a
>   mysterious source of power that can only be unlocked by the
>   Dragonborn.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> A Friend

How does he know that I am Dragonborn?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He is a plot device. It is never explained who "A Friend" might be.

As for how he knows you're Dragonborn, well, it's not every day that you see somebody FUS RO DAH'ing left and right and absorbing dragon souls...

Comment: I could have sworn it was explained at some point... But I haven't played Skyrim since December, so... I'm probably mistaken.

Comment: @Fluttershy are you possibly confusing it with the greybeads, who separately send you to find shouts? there's also IIRC one or two shouts the Blades direct to you...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That is entirely possible, and quite likely.

Comment: Thanks @kotekzot , I tend to agree with the explanation , but can it be logically derived from entire story , as possible candidates .

Comment: Well, if we're going to theorycraft, then it is most certainly not a single person, since <Location> can be anything starting with the Throat of the World and ending with a Dark Brotherhood sanctuary. No single person could know what happens in all those places.

Comment: @Fluttershy Are you thinking of the person from the Blades who contacts you via a letter during the main quest? (Vague to avoid spoilers.) That letter is also "from a friend", so I figured they're connected. If you did too, that might be what you're remembering.

Answer (score 1):

The game never tells you who he is, but probably it's not someone with a name since you can meet this someone and you'll still receive letters, maybe It's a NPC like "Stormcloak Soldier" or even the courier.

I always thought it was the courier, and It's not hard for people to discover who is the dragonborn.